# How to do query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    required: true
},
username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
role: {
    default: 'user',
    type: String, //we can consider using array of strings as in case user has several roles at the same time
    requierd: true
},
devices: [
    {
        id: '1',
        permissions:['start','stop']
    },

    {
        id: '2',
        permissions:['start','restart']
    }
]
});
```

How can i push new {id:'2', permissions:['stop']} without duplications, when i receive it in req.params.headers. I need to check is id:'2' already exist or not, then I'm shuld check is permission['stop'] is exist, and then if it isn't exist i should push it in  collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find any object that matchs either the id or the permission, you can do it with $or operand, something like this:

```
return User.findOne({ $or:[ {'devices.id': idValue}, {'devices.permissions': permission}  ]}).exec()
.then(user => {
    if(user) {
        console.log("We don't have to push it");
    } else {
        console.log("We have to push it");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for answers, just want to add that  at the beginning   devices[ ] array is empty....( in this case solutions that you provided isn't work well(

Comment: i should add new 
    {
        id: 'uniqueId',
        permissions:['permissions']
    } if it isn't exist.

or update if it already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` with `elemMatch` in condition to find the inner object. To avoid adding duplicate keys in array, you can use `$addToSet`

```
<>.update({"devices": { "$elemMatch": { "id": "2" }}},{ "$addToSet": { "devices.$.permissions": "stop" }})
```

Comment: also i want to check is ID is exist? if not push whole  {_id:'2', devices:['start']} object.